# How to return nested, one to many relationship in a ASP.NET MVC json response?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, autocomplete

**How would you format a Json response to include nested, one to many related data?**

My simple JQuery Autocomplete example.  The Linq2Sql is within.  The first part of this question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461664/using-jquery-how-do-you-select-one-element-based-on-anothers-name).  This uses a repository with Linq 2 SQL to send the response:

```
public IQueryable GetProductIDs(string myPrefix, int limit)
{
    return from z in db.Products
           where z.ItemNo.StartsWith(myPrefix)
           select new { id = z.ItemNo, name = z.DetailText, **** }; 
           //, This is where I need to assemble about 4 related product quantities
           //  like Qty1: 5, PricePer: $3, Qty2: 10, PricePer: $2, Qty3: 25, PricePer: $1
}
```

It returns a json object:

```
public ActionResult autocomplete(string q, int limit)
{
    var jsonData = plantRepository.GetProductIDs(q, limit);
    return Json(jsonData);
}
```

This currently returns data parse-able with JavaScript:

```
parse: function(data) {
    var rows = new Array();
    for( var i = 0; i<data.length; i++)
    {   rows[i] = {data:data[i], value:data[i].name, result:data[i].id }; }
    return rows;}
```

**So how to you format the Linq 2 SQL to return Json that can be parsed like data[i].price[1].qty, data[i].price[1].pricePer? (or simply add a multi-part object in the initializer?)**

I hope this makes sense.  I provided all the information to provide a context because the question in itself didn't make sense to me.

Comment: By the way, I am using the relation to populate an html <select> drop down menu.

Comment: Unless I'm missing the question... I don't know how to answer this without knowing the table structure.  Do you have a separate table with item - qty - price values?

Comment: The Product table has a one to many to Price(s) table having fields of "qty" and "pricePer".  So, the object would have product.prices.qty and product.prices.pricePer where prices is the relation.

Comment: Come to think of it, this is where LinqPad would do well.

Comment: Something like from p in Products where p.ItemNo == "CHOAK21" select new { first = new {a = "hello", b = "there" }, second = new {a = "hi", b = "No 2"} }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your projected object to include a property "price" so when it's serialized to json you can do like you quoted:

> data[i].price[1].qty

Change your linq query to something like this:

```
public IQueryable GetProductIDs(string myPrefix, int limit)
{
    return from prod in db.Products
           where prod.ItemNo.StartsWith(myPrefix)
           select new { id = prod.ItemNo, name = prod.DetailText, price = from pce in db.Price where pce.ItemNo equals prod.ItemNo select pce }; 
}
```

.. i haven't checked the syntax of the above but hopefully you get the idea. This way your anon object should have a property `id` and `name` (as before) and a collection called `price`. You could even go further to project the parts of `price` you want like this:

```
public IQueryable GetProductIDs(string myPrefix, int limit)
{
    return from prod in db.Products
           where prod.ItemNo.StartsWith(myPrefix)
           select new { id = prod.ItemNo, name = prod.DetailText, price = from pce in db.Price where pce.ItemNo equals prod.ItemNo select new { qty = pce.qty, pricePer = pce.pricePer }}; 
}
```

.. but i dont think that's necessary as the names are the same. Pls forgive my bad formatting.

Comment: That is great!  I just learned from a different post how to create Repository classes and use them as cookie cutters on the Linq to SQL responses to get Poco objects like you want in DDD.  Combine this with your technique and I have a GREAT way to create Models for my MVC views, plus expose these to JSON for JQuery.  Really cool!

Comment: It gets better too - if you adopt the TDD approach, i have a great way of parsing test json-formatted data to POCO object chains: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584074/which-json-deserializer-renders-ilistt-collections/1643883#1643883 (i'm using this in a project presenly - works a treat)